# Is there a list of hitscan abilities/weapons in Overwatch?

Tags: overwatch

There are a lot of different weapons and abilities in Overwatch. Some are hitscan ([I'm using the TF2 definition of hitscan](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Hitscan)), even if they have a projectile (I'm told Roadhog's hook is hitscan). This significantly impacts how you aim an attack - is there a list of which abilities and weapons fall into this category?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming we're using the Team Fortress 2 definition of HitScan...

- Ana: Biotic Rifle (scoped only)
- Bastion: Configuration: Recon, Configuration: Sentry
- D.Va: Fusion Cannons (Mech)
- Genji: Swift Strike, Deflect, Dragonblade
- Mei: Endothermic Blasters, Blizzard
- McCree: Peaceckeeper, Deadeye
- Reaper: Hellfire Shotguns, Death Blossom
- Reinheardt: Rocket Hammer
- Roadhog: Scrap Gun, Whole Hog
- Soldier: 76: Heavy Pulse Rifle
- Symmetra: Photon Projector, Sentry Turret
- Torbjörn: Forge Hammer, Build Turret
- Tracer: Pulse Pistols
- Widowmaker: Widow's Kiss
- Winston: Tesla Cannon, Primal Rage
- Zarya: Particle Cannon

Comment: I disagree with many aspects of this, particularly the idea that melee weapons and beam weapons (*especially* Symmetra and Winston, which lock onto a target as opposed to hitting a target in your croshair) are hitscan. I mean, Zarya, fine, but Symmetra's beam is basically a reverse heal beam. Mei's endothermic blaster is also not *really* a hitscan; it's more of a reverse flamethrower. Then again, I'm probably nitpicking and it doesn't realistically matter for either of those cases, since they're decidedly not projectile weapons.

Comment: Uhh, you have a few projectile weapons in this list.  Projectiles are, by definition, not hitscan.

Comment: For example, these weapons have projectiles:  D'va's Light Gun, Mercy's Caduceus Blaster, Soldier: 76's Pulse Rifle, Torbjorn's Rivet Gun, Roadhog's Scrap Gun, Tracer's Pulse Pistols.  That's in addition to the ones @Unionhawk has already commented on.

Comment: To be devil's advocate: a weapon having a *visual* projectile doesn't mean it can't be hitscan.

Comment: @twobugs And I think that is the case for 76, but mercy and d.va's pistols definitely feel like projectile weapons. But, I'm not able to retest that until May 24, so I don't really know if they are or not for certain.

Comment: @Unionhawk D'va pistols in her mech for are definitely hit scan, but her blaster in human form definitely uses projectiles.  I've played enough D'va to tell you that for a fact.

Comment: @twobugs Yes, but it's far more likely to be the case.  Otherwise, why bother drawing projectiles in the first place if the projectiles hitting isn't what's causing the damage?

Comment: I'm removing the checkmark because people having raised some significant concerns with the validity of this list. If it can be shown to be totally accurate (probably not viable until the 24th) I'll gladly return it

Comment: Soldier: 76's heavy pulse rifle is hitscan. It's the helix rockets that are projectile.

Comment: Genji's deflect is not hitscan by nature- however the nature of the attack reflected is preserved. That is to say, a reflected Pharah rocket will not become hitscan.